Shell.TitleView is covering up my NavigationPage tabs in .Net Maui
So for a Client we have a set of buttons up top set in the appshell.xml:
 <Shell.TitleView>

     <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
         <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1">
             <Button Text="User Info"
         FontSize="Micro"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         ImageSource="icon_user.png"
         MaximumHeightRequest="75"
         ContentLayout= "left,1"
         Clicked="User_Info_Button_Clicked"
 />
             <Button Text="In-Progress"
         FontSize="Micro"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         ImageSource="icon_view_in_progress_pso.png"
         MaximumHeightRequest="75"
         ContentLayout= "left,1"
         Clicked="InProgressPSO_Button_Clicked"
 />
             <Button Text="User Settings"
         FontSize="Micro"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         ImageSource="icon_settings.png"
         MaximumHeightRequest="75"
         ContentLayout= "left,1"
         Clicked="Settings_Button_Clicked"
         />
             <Button Text="Logout"
         FontSize="Micro"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         ImageSource="logout.png"
         MaximumHeightRequest="75"
         ContentLayout= "left,1"
         Clicked="Logout_Button_Clicked"
 />

         </HorizontalStackLayout>
     </Grid>
 </Shell.TitleView>
 <ShellContent x:Name="ShellWindow"/>

Looks like this:

That is also in connection with my Tabbed with two pages:
Log Page and a reporting page
whenever I use Shell.Current.GotoAsync(nameof(Pagetogoto))
we navigate away from the Navigation page and then use EITHER:
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MainPage))OR Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"../nameof(MainPage)) The buttons in my AppShell are covering my tabs on MainPage.
There is also the issue that whenever I navigate, more instances of MainPage are pushed onto the Navigation Stack. How can I maintain this?

From the screenshot you shared, I couldn't spot the problem you mentioned. Could you please post the full code of appshell.xml and the expected screenshot so that we can help you better?

that is the entire appshell.xml, when I navigate back to MainViewPage the buttons are aligned left, covering the tabs

I mean how can we reproduce this problem on our side? It is convenient for you, could you please post more code snippets so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

The issue is that  shell and tabbed pages dont get along well. We opted out of using the APPShell and I've put my toolbar in NavigationPage.TitleView
